# Concatenating a string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following line of code in jQuery:

```
inputPhoneNumber.val(inputPhoneCountry + inputPhoneMain);
```

What is the best way of adding two characters (00) in front of those two values inside the inputPhoneNumber variable? Regular JS string concatenation like:

```
inputPhoneNumber.val('00' + inputPhoneCountry + inputPhoneMain);
```

...doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see why

```
inputPhoneNumber.val('00' + inputPhoneCountry + inputPhoneMain);
```

should not work unless inputPhoneNumber is a `type=number` in which case it MIGHT remove the leading 0s (but it doesn't)

Try template literals and a text field

```
inputPhoneNumber.val(`00${inputPhoneCountry}${inputPhoneMain}`);
```

In testing it does not make a difference

```js
const inputPhoneCountry = 31;
const inputPhoneMain = 612345678;
$("#inputPhoneNumber1").val(`00${inputPhoneCountry}${inputPhoneMain}`);
$("#inputPhoneNumber2").val(`00${inputPhoneCountry}${inputPhoneMain}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="inputPhoneNumber1" />
<input type="text" id="inputPhoneNumber2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
inputPhoneNumber.val('00' + inputPhoneCountry + inputPhoneMain);
```

This works too:

```
inputPhoneNumber.val(`00${inputPhoneCountry}${inputPhoneMain}`);
```

Still if it doenst work for you, you can break them and use only one `var` for it.
Example:

```js
var inputPhoneCountry = 10;
var inptPhoneMain = 20;
var finalNumber = '00' + inputPhoneCountry + inptPhoneMain;

alert(finalNumber);
```